# Does a Pokemon gain EVs when participating in a Max Raid Battle?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I do know that Pokemon do not gain experience after a Max Raid Battle ends; however, I'm asking this to be sure, since I am raising some Pokemon and want to use them in the process. When a Max Raid Battle is won, do participating Pokemon receive Effort Values based off of the species battled, as in wild battles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Max Raid battles do not provide EVs. This is confirmed [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/259372-pokemon-sword/answers/528915-do-max-raid-battles-yield-ev-points), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonSwordAndShield/comments/dyk7gx/can_pok%C3%A9mon_gain_ev_after_max_raid_battle/), and [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/78183399).

To test this, one of the sources took a Ferrothorn that had no EVs in any stat into a raid battle. After the boss was defeated, they used berries that reduces EVs on the Ferrothorn for each stat. Each berry gave the message indicating no stats were lost